# JSON parsing using [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataJson options:0 error:&error] thowing nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

> error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.)
>   UserInfo=0x7fa4e25da7c0 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

If changing `NSData` to `NSString` , response is getting but using

```
id jsonData =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataJson options:0 error:&error]
```

showing above error, and response `nil`.

Comment: "garbage at end". your json is corrupt.

Comment: Hi Marc B , how do i correct it, if I am using this in same class I am able to get the response with this, but I made one common method in singleton class there it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the mistake, that I was appending the response every time, which was creating problem.Now problem is sort out.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I use online JSON validators to check JSON.
Here is few links:

http://jsonlint.com (my favourite)

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate

Comment: I have triend ...there it is showing invalid response. But my doubt is that same method i am using in same class there it is responding fine and giving my acurate respone and also here also if I triend to convert nsdata to nasstring it is giving the response but for [nsjsonserialization jsonObjectWithData] it is not working ... plz explain, if I need to do something else